# Selenium id=email not being found

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium WebDriver to try and capture an email address field to log into our site.

My code to detect the email address field so I can insert the email is:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id(("email"))));
WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
email.sendKeys(email);
```

The HTML on the web page is this:

```
<input type="text" title="Email Address" class="input-text required-entry validate-email"
id="email" value="" name="login[username]">
```

The problem is, Selenium is reporting it can't locate the id=email ???

Browser is IE. Works ok in FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE sometimes renders the page differently. Are you sure HTML is the same in IE?

Since your code works fine in FF and Chrome, all I can suggest now is to try different locators. But please post your exact stacktrace, what exact exception is.

Replace

```
By.id("email")
```

with one of the followings

```
By.cssSelector("#email")
By.xpath(".//input[@id='email']")

By.cssSelector("input[title='Email Address']")
By.xpath(".//input[@title='Email Address']")
```

Answer (score 0):

The xpath may change if any new field is added so always better to use the name or id

```
driver.findElement(By.name("login[username]"));
```